# Wordpress HTTP API code 400

Tags: php, wordpress, api, curl

I'm working on an API integration from a POS system which requires a security token. In the API documentation & curl the response is ok.

Curl

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: */*" -d "{
   \"deviceId\": \"api\",
   \"password\": \"password\",
   \"username\": \"ursername@pos.com\"
}" "http://staging-exact-integration.posios.com/PosServer/rest/token"
```

Request URL

http://staging-exact-integration.posios.com/PosServer/rest/token

However when I tried to write it in Wordpress HTTP API I get a 400 bad request. Saying

```
[body] => {"description":"Could not read JSON: No content to map due to end-of-input\n at [Source: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput@62421932; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input\n at [Source: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput@62421932; line: 1, column: 1]"}
```

In Wordpress

```
$url = "http://staging-exact-integration.posios.com/PosServer/rest/token";
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    "headers" => array(
        //"Authorization" => "Basic",
        "Content-Type" => "application/json"
    ),
    //"body" => "grant_type=client_credentials",
    //"httpversion" => "1.1",

    "deviceId" => "api",
    "password" => "password",
    "username" => "username@pos.com"
    )
);

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
   echo 'Response:<pre>';
   print_r( $response );
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

What is required in the Wordpress HTTP API?

Comment: Where you were test this API's ? Postman ?

Comment: this is in wordpress. I have tested this in postman as well it gets me the same request & error mesage

Answer (score 0):

First of all changed Basic Auth to oAuth and add JSON just like this.

```
{
  "title": {
  "raw": "Hello Checking"
}
```

It's working for me in past. You should have to look into this and test in POSTMAN.